# salvar no arquivo txt o resultado da consulta sql no firebird usando Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, txt

Preciso salvar o resultado de uma consulta dentro do arquivo txt separando por um delimitador, sou extremamente novo no delphi e firebird, então qualquer ajuda é de bem vinda

código abaixo:

```
procedure TForm1.btPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
var arquivo: TextFile;
var dados: string;
var I: Integer;
begin

  if EdLoja.Text = '' then
  begin

  IBQuery1.Close;
  IBQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  IBQuery1.SQL.Add('select COUNT(CDLOJA) from lojas');
  IBQuery1.Open;

  while not IBQuery1.eof do
    begin

IBQuery2.Close;
IBQuery2.SQL.Clear;

IBQuery2.SQL.Add('select * from lojas where CDLOJA = '+(EdLoja.Text)+'');
IBQuery2.SQL.Add('and p.cdloja = '+(IBQuery1.Eof)+'');
IBQuery2.SQL.Add('and p.dtlancamento >= '+ FormatdateTime('mm"-"dd"-"yyyy',StrToDate(EdDataIni.Text)) + '');
IBQuery2.SQL.Add('and p.dtlancamento <= '+ FormatdateTime('mm"-"dd"-"yyyy',StrToDate(EdDataFim.Text)) + '');

IBQuery2.Open;
IBQuery2.First;
AssignFile(arquivo, 'c:\\'+IBQuery2.FieldByName('CDLOJA').AsString+'Vencimento.txt');
Rewrite(arquivo);


dados := IBQuery2.FieldByName('CDLOJA').AsString + ';' + IBQuery2.FieldByName('CDBAIRRO').AsString;
WriteLn(arquivo, dados);
IBQuery2.Next;

CloseFile(arquivo);

end;

  ShowMessage('ARQUIVOS GERADO COM SUCESSO!');

  end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Ezequiel, vc tem alguns problemas em sua pergunta e um deles é a formatação de código, para isso [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/349874/edit) e use ctrl + K. Seria legal melhorar, para evitar o fechamento e tente sempre fazer perguntas que serão úteis para outros na comunidade, veja [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesta parte precisa de um ajuste:

```
 while not IBQuery2.eof do

 begin
  WriteLn(arquivo);
  IBQuery2.Next;
 end;
```

para:

```
while not IBQuery2.eof do
begin
  vTexto := IBQuery2.FieldByName('NOME_CAMPO_1').AsString + ';' + IBQuery2.FieldByName('NOME_CAMPO_2').AsString
  WriteLn(arquivo, vTexto);
  IBQuery2.Next;
end;
```

Comment: Boa tarde junior, seguinte, essa parte pelo que vi deu super certo, vTexto substitui por dados, string certo?

Comment: Porem ele entra em loop infinito por causa da query1, oque eu quero fazer é o seguinte, ele faz o primeiro select, conta quantas lojas tem, e então no select seguinte colocando o codigo de cada loja, ele tras um select por vez e salva em arquivos separados um loop por vez, buscando na loja apontada conforme o loop da query1 e ja salva no aquivoloja1, proximo arquivoloja2 e etc até terminar o loop

Comment: Observe antes do `CloseFile(arquivo);` você colocou `IBQuery2.Next;` e depois não mandou o `IBQuery1` prosseguir, ele vai ficar ali para sempre, então retire o `IBQuery2.Next;` e coloque `IBQuery1.Next` apos o `CloseFile`